# Enum class out of scope - C++

Tags: c++, class, enums, scope

this is my current program
Header file

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
class Board {
enum class EnemyPiece {HIT, MISS, EMPTY};
enum class PlayerPiece {AIRCRAFT, BATTLESHIP, CRUISER, SUBMARINE, PATROL, EMPTY};
  private:
     PlayerPiece playerboard[100];
     PlayerPiece enemyboard[100];
  public:
     Board();
     void reset(PlayerPiece *a , PlayerPiece *b);
   };
#endif
```

And here is the cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Board.h"

using namespace std;

 Board::Board()
 {
  reset(playerboard, enemyboard);
 }

 void Board::reset(PlayerPiece *year, PlayerPiece *month)
 {
  std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type<PlayerPiece>::type>(PATROL) << std::endl;
 }
```

In the member function I am trying to cast an enum type however no matter where I place the deceleration done in the header file I keep getting
"PATROL" was not declared in this scope
Is there something I am doing wrong? Should the enum class be put somewhere else?

Comment: Use `PlayerPiece::PATROL`.

Comment: And stop using CAPITAL letters, that dreadful hack isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: `#ifndef BOARD_H #define BOARD_H #ifndef BOARD_H` ... how's that supposed to work? Your enum definitions are private, how is anyone going to call the `reset` function?

Comment: Why do you have twice the `#ifndef BOARD_H`? Is that a copy/paste error or it is really present in your file? In any case you must remove the second occurrence..

Comment: Sorry for the second occurrence, that was a typo when copying.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `enum class`, the tokens are scoped under the type. Hence, you need to use `PlayerPiece::PATROL` instead of just `PATROL`.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **7.2 Enumeration declarations**
>
> ...
>
> 2 ... The *enum-keys* `enum class` and `enum struct` are semantically equivalent; an enumeration type declared with one of these is a *scoped enumeration*, and its *enumerators* are *scoped enumerators*.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Board::PlayerPiece::PATROL
```

of just

```
PlayerPiece::PATROL
```

because the enumeration is used inside the class scope.

and declare the enumerations like public if you are going to accept them as arguments of a public member function.

And it seems there is a typo

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
#ifndef BOARD_H
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Remove the last `#ifndef`